# Router.get usage for rendering index.HTML in koa

Tags: html, typescript, frontend, router, koa2

Tried `router.get('/', async ctx => ctx.redirect('index.html'))` for the initial routing, but failed.

Is there any other method to redirect to index.HTML / index.ejs from `router.get()`?

I'm new to Koa. Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not enough to just redirect. You need to tell koa how to serve a static file ... `koa-static` is a good package for that.

Lets assume you place two files into a subdirectory `./public`

- index.html
- redirect.html (to demonstrate also redirecting)

Then do

```
npm install koa
npm install koa-static
```

You code then should basically look like:

```js
'use strict';
const koaStatic = require('koa-static');
const Koa = require('koa');
const app = new Koa();

// possible redirect middleware
const redirect = async function(ctx, next) {
    if (ctx.request.url === '/') {
        ctx.redirect('redirected.html')
    } else {
        await next()
    }
}

app.use(redirect); // this will add your redirect middleware
app.use(koaStatic('./public')); // serving static files

app.listen(3000);
```

**Remarks**

- if you now in your browser call `localhost:3000/index.html` ... you get the content of `index.html`
- if you call `localhost:3000/` ... you get the content of `redirect.html`
- you actually do not need the redirection middleware (shown above). koa-static redirects `/` calls to `index.html`

Comment: I want to hit two service calls before redirecting to my index.html.So only on success response , i will be navigating to index.html. Can you please provide any solutions for that?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Can you describe it more explicitly? Service calls to what? Are they also asynchronous? DB or Rest calls? ... actually this extends your question quite a bit. So your original title would not fit anymore. Maybe just mark this one as answered and open a new one.

Comment: Let say i have to invoke an api(Rest calls) before rendering the html.Okay i will open a new one for this question . Thanks Sebastian